# Graph of $dQ/dt$ discontinuous

Tags: electric-current, charge, differentiation, calculus

Charge is quantised then why how do we define $dQ/dt$ as current when graph of $Q$ v/s $x$ will be discontinuous and hence non-differentiable.

Is it an approximation we use?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/460882/